# Error in weka.core.converter.TextDirectory.Loader

Tags: machine-learning, ubuntu-12.04, weka

I want to convert text files to arff files in a directory.
When I run the below command in a linux terminal:

> java weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir weka

... I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/core/converters/TextDirectoryLoader
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader. Program will exit.
```

Please suggest how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message tells us that the TextDirectoryLoader class is not present on your current search path. Probably it was not installed with your version of Weka.

According to their [wiki](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA), this class is only available for Weka versions greater than 3.5.3. Check your installation directory again and look for this class. Else use TextDirectoryToArff

**How to change the classpath**

You have to edit (sudo gedit or sudo vim) the .bashrc file located at your home directory (~) and add this line:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:[new_path]
```

Where your [new_path] is something like /home/users/username/downloads/weka/weka.jar

EDIT: Noticed that you should add the weka.jar to the classpath, and not the weka installation directory.

Comment: there are 2 folders of weka namely weka.jarr and weka-3.6.6.jar in /usr/share/java folder in my system.Still getting the same error on using TextDirectoryToArff . @KuramaYoko

Comment: I see your version is 3.6.6, so TexDirectoryLoader is the way to go. Those two "folders" you mentioned are actually the binary to execute the Weka package. The installation directory should be the folder you unzipped from the weka website.
Add this folder to your CLASSPATH on your .bashrc file

Comment: How to edit .bashrc file . please guide :) @KuramaYoko

Comment: Added new instructions to my answer